# How to make a pop-up with a close button on the top of a full screen video

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have created a small sample project in which I play a video and at every given interval of time I show a pop-up box with a close button in it while pausing the video. When the close button is clicked, the video resumes. The problem that I've been facing is that when the video is played full screen, the pop-up is shown ( I've used maximum z-index value for the pop-up division) but the button for close is not working.

```js
var det = true;
var i = 1;
var popInterval = 2;
var cl;
var j = popInterval;
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrp");

function check()
{
    if(vid.currentTime > 0)
    {
        //clearInterval(cl);
        startPop();
    }
}
cl = setInterval(check, 1);

function startPop()
{
    if(vid.currentTime == j || (vid.currentTime > j && vid.currentTime < j+0.1))
    {
        vid.pause();
        wrapper.style.display = "block";
        ++i;
        j = popInterval * i;
    }
    var cls = setTimeout(startPop, 1);
    if(vid.currentTime == vid.duration)
    {
        j = popInterval;
        i = 1
        clearTimeout(cls);
    }
}

function closePop()
{
    wrapper.style.display = "none";
    vid.play();
}
```

```css
.wrapper
{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 2147483647;
}

.content
{
  postion: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<video id = "video" controls = "" width = "1000px" height = "700px">
  <source src = "https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" />
</video>

<div id = "wrp" class = "wrapper"> <!-- pop-up division-->
  <div class = "content">
    <h1>You are seeing a pop-up!</h1>
    <a href = "javascipt:void(0)" id = "btn" onclick = "closePop()">Close this pop-up</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 1):

Stack overflow editor contains code snippet tool to add a working code. I've transformed your code using that. It actually helps everyone to see and make edits to a non-working code.

**Issue in your code:** Your code was working but have identified that anchor tag was improperly closed by a button tag and may be it was because of that.

### About `z-index`

- There is no need to use a maximum value of [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). This defines the stack order of elements within a container. Since your popup is already defined after video, it'll appear on top of it even without giving a `z-index`.
- Try to put it before video and you'll see that it is not visible because it is behind the video element. In order to resolve, and as far as your video and popup elements are inside a parent container, setting the z-index to 1 will make the popup element appear on top of the video element.

```js
var det = true;

var i = 1;
var popInterval = 2;
var cl;
var j = popInterval;
var vid = document.getElementById("video");

var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrp");

function check() {
  if (vid.currentTime > 0) {
    //clearInterval(cl);
    startPop();
  }
}
cl = setInterval(check, 1);

function startPop() {
  if (vid.currentTime == j || (vid.currentTime > j && vid.currentTime < j + 0.1)) {
    vid.pause();
    wrapper.style.display = "block";
    ++i;
    j = popInterval * i;
  }
  var cls = setTimeout(startPop, 1);
  if (vid.currentTime == vid.duration) {
    j = popInterval;
    i = 1
    clearTimeout(cls);
  }
}

function closePop() {
  wrapper.style.display = "none";
  vid.play();
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
}

.content {
  postion: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<body>

  
  <div id="wrp" class="wrapper">
    <!-- pop-up division-->

    <div class="content">

      <h1>You are seeing a pop-up!</h1>
      <a href="javascipt:void(0)" id="btn" onclick="closePop()">Close this pop-up</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <video id="video" controls="" width="1000px" height="700px">
    <source src = "video.mp4" />
  </video>


</body>
```

Comment: The pop-up now does not even come over to the top of video, it remains in the background, when the video is played full screen. Before, it at least came over in front of the full screen video, but the close button was not working

Comment: Sorry I didn't take fullscreen into account. In that case giving max `z-index` is more appropriate.